# How to get a value from an array

Tags: php, foreach

Not sure why I can't this to work. My json is:

```
[values] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [field] => id1
                    [value] => 985
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [field] => id2
                    [value] => 6395
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [field] => memo
                    [value] => abcde
                )
```

I simply want the values of id2

I tried:

```
foreach ($json['values'] as $values) {  
    foreach ($json as $key=>$data) {
        if ($data['field'] == 'id2') {
            $result = $data['value'];
            print '<br>value: '.$result;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks. I know this should be relatively simple and I'm sure I've done this correctly before.

Comment: Why don't you just print `$key` and `$data` out in your inner foreach loop so you at least know that you're looking at the right data?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a comma after `[field] => id2` etc.?

Comment: @Fred-ii-: The array shown is not PHP syntax at all, but just a debug output …

Comment: Your second foreach  you should be using $values instead of $json

Comment: @ElefantPhace has hit the nail on the head there. He's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($json['values'] as $values) { //you're looping your first array, puttin each row in a variable $values
    foreach ($values as $key=>$data) {  //you're looping inside values taking the array index $key and the value inside that index $data
        if ($key == 'id2') { //test if $key (index) is = to id2
            print '<br>value: '.$value; // print the value inside that index
        }
    }
}
```

this is just an explanation, to what is going wrong with your code, but as @Pawel_W there is no need for the second foreach loop you can directly test

```
if($values['field']=='id2'){ print $values['value'];}
```

Comment: You do know how to use comments within php, correct?

Comment: You just pass your time criticizing? It is a q&a website not a criticism one

Answer (score 1):

there's no need for inner loop, after the first one `$values` already contain the exact array that you are looking for

```
foreach ($json['values'] as $values) // $values contain 
{
    if ($values['field'] == 'id2')
    {
        $result = $values['value'];
        print '<br>value: '.$result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add some explanation such as what he was doing wrong. Wait this is probably wrong anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use [array_search](https://www.php.net/array_search).
And here is [recursive array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php#91365) ;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there might be multiple fields with the same name and you want them all as array, here's an alternative take:

```
array_filter(array_map(function($item) { return $item['field'] == 'id2' ? $item['value'] : null; }, $json['values']));
```

If your field names are always unique and you just want a single scalar:

```
array_reduce($json['values'], function($current, $item) { return $item['field'] == 'id2' ? $item['value'] : $current; });
```

(note that this one is not ideal since it will walk all the array even if match is found in first element)

And [**here's a gist**](https://gist.github.com/tadas-s/9012754) with both in this and function form + output.